# How can i properly simplify my url using variables?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm trying to make an esports web page, but first I'm playing with the API.

the problem is that when I want to simplify my url like this.

```
var url = "https://api.pandascore.co/lol/champions/2524?token="+accesskey+""

var accesskey = "example"
```

sends me an 401 error or accesskey invalid but when I code it like this

```
var url = "https://api.pandascore.co/lol/champions/2524?token="example"
```

it works, so I don't know if I'm simplifying bad my code :(.

Answer (score 0):

+"" isn't necessary try with just:

```
var url = "https://api.pandascore.co/lol/champions/2524?token="+accesskey
```

You can also do it with template literals like this

```
var url =`https://api.pandascore.co/lol/champions/2524?token=${accesskey}`;
```